# How do I get rid of buttons in parent component when dropdown menu is visible in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, css-position

I created a dropdown menu shown below and whenever it is visible, the buttons beneath it are still active/visible. How do I make it so that the dropdown menu is the most top layer? the partially visible ellipsis buttons are functional which is not what I want.

[image]

**Dropdown.jsx**

```
const Dropdown = props => {
  const [showOptions, setShowOptions] = useState(false);

  const toggleOptions = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowOptions(!showOptions);
  }

  const buttonLabel = (<i className='fa fa-ellipsis-v' />)

  return (
    <div className='employees-li-options'>
      <FormButton
        label={buttonLabel}
        id='employees-li-options-button'
        type='button'
        onClick={toggleOptions}
        />
      {
        showOptions ? (
          <div className='employees-li-options-visible'>
            <FormButton
              type='button'
              label='active'
              />
            <FormButton
              type='button'
              label='inactive'
              />
            <FormButton
              type='button'
              label='deactivated'
              />
            <FormButton
              type='button'
              label='invite pending'
              />
          </div>
        ) : (
          null
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
};
```

**css**

```
.employees-li-options-visible {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: $white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: space-evenly;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px $light-gray1; 
  padding: 1em 1em 0.1em 1em;
}
```

Comment: Try adding z-index: -1 to the visible ellipsis buttons

Comment: I've managed to handle it in a hacky way by adding margins but I would still love to know what the issue is for future reference. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I think the problem is with position: absolute. with this property, element will be positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. Your previous eclipse buttons are already in the document and positioned. Your white div element is in the bottom of the order and buttons are in the top of the order. So you have to manually push it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS. Just add `z-index` style to the parent OR to the dropdown itself. The parent element should still be visible behind the dropdown.
[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

```css
// To the parent
#parent {
    z-index: -1;
}

// To the dropdown
.employees-li-options-visible {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```